# Node JS can't find module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a `files.js` file and am requiring it at the start of my code.

When I use:

```
const files = require('./lib/files');
```

I get this error:

> Error: Cannot find module './lib/files'

However if I test it with another one of the files in the same folder like:

```
const files = require('./lib/repo');
```

It runs.

`files.js`:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  getCurrentDirectoryBase: () => {
    return path.basename(process.cwd());
  },

  directoryExists: (filePath) => {
    return fs.existsSync(filePath);
  }
};
```

I would use `tree` command however I have too many node modules installed to show it correctly so:

[image]

Comment: Do you have the export syntax correct in the file you are targeting.

Comment: Theres no syntax errors and I gave it a look through and seems fine

Comment: post content of `files.js`

Comment: added it to the post

Comment: As @Bibberty pointed out, the most likely reason is you are missing export on files.js file. At the end of files.js, you should have `module.exports.Something = something;`.

Comment: I have that @AbrarHossain so do I need to add anything else

Comment: Can you please post your directory & file structure for the pertinent area?

Comment: tip: if your just returning, save 2 lines by doing `getCurrentDirectoryBase: () => path.basename(process.cwd())`, and `directoryExists: filePath => fs.existsSync(filePath);`

Answer (score -2):

```
const { getCurrentDirectoryBase, directoryExists } = require('./lib/files')
```